# Randomly adding classes to elements using Math.floor, Math.Random

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, random, floor

## Objective

I have 60 hockey `.players`. There are ten goalies (players numbered 1-10), twenty defensemen (players numbered 11-30) and thirty forwards (players numbered 31-60). On click, the button `.btn--random` should randomly add the class `is-active` to `two goalie, six defensemen and twelve forwards` and remove the class `is-inactive`

## Problem

- When I generate the numbers using a series of for loops and a
  combination of `Math.floor(Math.random())` sometimes the random
  generated numbers are the same, which can't happen as each player is
  unique and can only be chosen once.

  I've thought about `forEach` or `indexOf` to help solve this problem,
  but I'm pretty lost on how the numbers generated will add the class
  of `is-active` to the appropriate player in the list of the 60
  players. **It's specifically this line `<div class="picked is-inactive">` that should be altered in the HTML**

### scripts.js - This is how far I've gotten

```
function randomSelection(min, max) {
    $(".btn--random").on("click", function(){

        // There are 60 hockey players in total
        // The first player is 1, the second player is 2 and so on ...
        // There are 10 goalies, 20 defencemen and 30 forwards


        // Generate two numbers between 1-10
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            var randTwo = Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1);
            console.log(randTwo);

            if (randTwo === randTwo) {

            }
        };

        // Currently generates six numbers between 1-20
        // Should generate six numbers between 11-30
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            var randSix = Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 1);
            console.log(randSix);

            if (randSix === randSix) {

            }
        };

        // Currently generates twelve numbers between 1-30
        // Should generate two numbers between 31-60
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            var randTwelve = Math.floor(Math.random()*30 + 1);
            console.log(randTwelve);

            if (randTwelve === randTwelve) {

            }
        };

        // Store the 20 randomly generated numbers into an array?
        var array = []

        // Add the class `is-active` based on the numbers generated
        var player = $(".player");
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()* 60);
        player.eq(rand).addClass("is-active");
    });
} randomSelection();
```

### index.html (snippet)

```
<button class="btn btn--random">Random</button>

<div class="player player--goalie year--1990">
                    <div class="tooltip tooltip--tall">
                        <p class="tooltip__name">Brian Elder</p>
                        <p class="tooltip__hometown"><span>Hometown:</span> Oak Lake, Man.</p>
                        <p class="tooltip__years"><span>Years Played:</span> 1992-1997</p>
                        <div class="tooltip__stats--inline">
                            <div class="stats__group stats--games">
                                <p class="stats__header">GP</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--games">110</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--goalsag">
                                <p class="stats__header">GA</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--goalsag">2.00</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">3.12</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">3.46</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">2.70</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--savep">
                                <p class="stats__header">SAV%</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--savep">.909</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.886</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.884</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">.906</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="stats__group stats--shutouts">
                                <p class="stats__header">SO</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">0</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">0</p>
                                <p class="stats__number stats__number--shutouts">3</p>
                                <p class="stats__number">2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- tooltip__stats--inline -->
                    </div> <!-- tooltip -->
                    <div class="player__headshot player--elder">
                        <div class="picked is-inactive"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    </div>
                    <p class="player__name">Brian Elder</p>
                    <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
                </div>
```

Comment: can you use an external library like lodash or underscore? If you, it might be worth creating three arrays representing the goalies, defence men and forwards. Once this has been done, shuffle these arrays using lodash or underscore. Now all you need to do is pop() out the last guy and you;ve got your random player without duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please take a look at this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".btn--random").on("click", function() {

    var goalies_array = getRandomNumbers(1, 10, 2);
    $(".goalies").text(goalies_array.join(","));
    var defensemen_array = getRandomNumbers(11, 30, 6);
    $(".defensemen").text(defensemen_array.join(","));
    var forwards_array = getRandomNumbers(31, 60, 12);
    $(".forwards").text(forwards_array.join(","));

    var players_array = goalies_array.concat(defensemen_array).concat(forwards_array);

    // Add the class `is-active` based on the numbers generated
    var player = $(".player");
    $(".is-active").removeClass("is-active").addClass("is-inactive");


    $.each(players_array, function(index, value) {
      var player_index = value - 1; //we are using 0 based indexing
      player.eq(player_index).find(".is-inactive").removeClass("is-inactive").addClass("is-active");
    });


  });
});


function getRandomNumbers(start, end, howMany) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = start, j = 0; i <= end; j++, i++)
    arr[j] = i
  arr.sort(function() {
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) - 1)
  });

  return arr.splice(0, howMany)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn--random">Random</button>
<br/>
<br/>Goalies
<div class="goalies"></div>
<br/>Defensemen
<div class="defensemen"></div>
<br/>Forwards
<div class="forwards"></div>
<br/>
```

Comment: This is very close. I haven't seen any repeating digits so far which is good. The only part that is missing is adding a class of `is-active` to the divs of the players of those randomly generated numbers. There are 60 players in total.

Comment: i saw your HTML but couldn't figure out where are the 60 DOM elements with `players` class. Could you please let us know the exact HTML structure so that it will be easy to assign `is-active` to those elements.

Comment: It's specifically in this line `<div class="picked is-inactive">` For the randomly chosen players based off the numbers generated, the class `is-inactive` has to be removed an `is-active` should be added.

Comment: This works great! I was hoping you could elaborate a little bit more about what is happening inside the function and with .each and .eq

Answer (score 1):

You are using correct function to generate random number but you need to specify range between which you want random numbers.

You should use following :

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*30 + 31)    //generate random number between 31-60
Math.floor(Math.random()*20 + 11)    //generate random number between 11-30
```

31/21 is start number

30/20 is number of possible result

Comment: This definitely helpful, but still doesn't solve the duplication of randomly generated numbers.

Comment: in any way you want numbers in array so before pushing number in array you check if number is already in array. This will solve your duplication of number problem

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lodash solution

https://jsfiddle.net/whxtx58v/

The important bit is this function here:

```
function generateRoster(min, max){
    var players = [];
  for(var i = min; i <= max; i++){
    players.push(i);
  }
  return _.shuffle(players);
}
```

What this does is takes in the min and the max of your player numbers, generates an array and shuffles it. Then to get two random players, you can simply take the first two elements.

Comment: Instead of printing it like in the jsfiddle above, you could then do something like  var player = $(".player"); player[*number*].addClass('is-active')

Comment: This works for the number generating part. The second part is how to randomly add a class of `is-active` to divs of each of the players based off those numbers? It's specifically this line that needs to be changed `<div class="picked is-inactive">`

Comment: Assuming that there are 60 .player divs and that they are in player order, you could simply choose the nth div and add the class 'is-active' to those

`var players = $('.player');
var goalieRoster = generateRoster(1, 10);
_.take(goalieRoster, 2).forEach(function(number){
  player.eq(number).addClass('is-active');
});`

Comment: Could you update your code snippet above, that would be helpful